# Convert from Option<String> to non-empty &str w/o move

Tags: rust

Is there a more efficient way to do this:

```
let s_opt = Some("Abc".to_string());
let s2 = &s_opt.clone().unwrap_or("".to_string());
println!("s_opt = {s_opt:?}, s2 = {s2:?}");
```

If I omit the `clone()` call, there will be a problem, because `unwrap_or` *moves* the wrapped `String` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found what I was looking for:

```
let s2 = s_opt.as_deref().unwrap_or("");
```

It's a bit shorter and avoids cloning the original `String` value.

Comment: Since [`<&str as Default>::default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/primitive.str.html#method.default) "*creates an empty str*", you can actually use `.unwrap_or_default()` instead of `.unwrap_or("")` here.

Comment: @eggyal In any other situation I'd prefer `unwrap_or_default()` but in this particular case `unwrap_or("")` is both shorter and (to me) more readable. :)

Comment: @eggyal Thanks for this note. I agree with @user4815162342 though - for me `unwrap_or("")` also seems slightly better in this case.